# Reading integers from a file returns incorrect output (ifstream)

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

In my attempt to make an automatic Sudoku solver in **C++**, the first step I need is to read the 9x9 grid from a file. Currently I just try to simply read the data, and display it as output, however the output is not correct. My code is as following:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Initialize string for the lines to be read in
    string line;

    // Create the object to read the file "data.txt"
    ifstream sudokuData("data.txt");

    // Check if file opened properly
    if (!sudokuData.good()) {
    cout << "Couldn't open the file.\n";
    }

    // Read only if file exists
    if ( sudokuData.is_open() ) {

        cout << "Starting to read from file... \n";

        // Read as long as there are lines in the file
        while ( getline(sudokuData,line) ) {
            cout << line << '<\n';
        }

        // Close file once done reading
        sudokuData.close();

    } else {
        // If file cannot be read, inform the user
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Which from all I can find, is correct. The data file contains the numbers from 1 to 9 in each row, separated by a space. An example line would be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

But when I run the code, I get the following output:

```
Starting to read from file 
153709 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 815370
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 38ms)
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

I'm using NetBeans 8.0 as IDE, if that is of any use...

Comment: where do you ge the getline() method ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Double check to see if there are garbage, non-printable, utf-8 encoded, or Unicode characters in the file.

Comment: The output is copy-pasted from the "Project name (Run)" fan, and it is the full output. And the "Starting to read from file" part, is the line I make it print through the code (using cout).

Comment: yea the code looks good, probably the file ?

Comment: I created the file using Notepad (standard Windoze one), and it only contains the numbers 1-9 and spaces. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. At line 27 you define a multi-byte char constant with `'<\n'`. Remove the < sign and it should work fine.

Comment: It's always the typos that gets you... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about it. GCC 4.6 gives a warning:
`file.cpp:27:29: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`